# iPhone 7 using a lot of Wi-Fi data

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, wifi, data

From 27th October, my iPhone started using a lot of Wi-Fi Bandwidth and I can't use the Wi-Fi for any other purposes.
Things I checked:

1. Checked for WhatsApp chat backup, No.
2. Checked for Translate offline languages, No.
3. Checked for iCloud Backup, No.

   [image: iCloud Backup]
4. iOS update, No the auto update is off. Currently using iOS 14.0.1. Since all bandwidth is used I can't update it manually, so I didn't try.
5. Auto App-Update, checked and it is already set to not auto update over Cellular and Wi-Fi.

After all these steps, the problem is still not solved. So I reset my iPhone deleting all data.

Then I restored all data from iTunes Backup and tried to download all apps and it took a huge time and lot of data because something is running in background. So I paused some of apps from downloading and then cancelled the download of these big apps like Apple Office Apps, Google Office Apps and MS Office Apps and GarageBand.

I had a lot of photos and some files in the Files app in On my iPhone part and not in iCloud Drive.
My iCloud drive and iCloud backup is always turned off.

[image: iCloud turned off]

Then I deleted all my Apps to check if any app is doing it.
First WhatsApp and then every other non-apple apps + Watch app and Translate app.

It didn't work.

On 3rd November, I deleted all the files in my On my iPhone in Files app and deleted all my photos.

[image: My iPhone storage]

Now the phone, despite having nothing, is still using all the Wi-Fi bandwidth.

There is no way to check the Wi-Fi usage from iPhone. But the battery information shows this data.

[image: Battery]

I have never tried with cellular data since I don't have a cellular plan and this king of data usage will cost a lot of money if cellular data is consumed.

Also, now randomly, the phone is getting disabled for 5 minutes, mostly when I press the power button or when I restart the iPhone.

This is not Jailbroken or anything.

Has anyone experienced the same issue or any advice for me to solve this problem?

I have now deleted the Contacts app and the Wi-Fi usage became zero.
I restored my iTunes backup and deleted the Apple apps, but still the same problem of using a lot of Wi-Fi data exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution.

I have already turned off iCloud drive and iCloud photos. But for some reason, the phone was uploading my 50+GB data to iCloud drive. When I clicked my iCloud it was showing that there is a Backup in iCloud, the size is not showing up as it is not complete.
But on clicking it, it says 57GB needs to be uploaded or sort of. When I cancelled the backup, the phone is now normal, not using any extra data.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. Solutions like these are important to be able to help other questioners directly :-)